# PDO pass array into stored procedure

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

How can I pass array into:

```
$query = 'CALL myStoredProcedure(:array)'
```

to use it in IN clause of that stored procedure?

BTW: its not duplicate. Passing array into stored procedure is NOT EQUAL to passing array into SELECT query directly. So duplicate mark is wrong. I can pass array as a set of (?,?,?,?,?) but how should i call unknown count of parameters inside IN clause?

```
$params = array(1, 21, 63, 171);
$place_holders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?'));
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM contacts WHERE id IN ($place_holders)");
$sth->execute($params);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved!**

***PHP:***

```
$params = implode(',', $array);//string arrays should escape each element with quotes
$stmt = $db->prepare('CALL myProcedure(:array)');
$stmt->bindParam(':array', $params, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

***STORED PROCEDURE:***

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `myProcedure`(IN `array` VARCHAR(2048))
#VARCHAR(2048) - maximum expected total length of imploded array
BEGIN
SET @query:= CONCAT(
'SELECT
    *
FROM
    `some` AS `table`
WHERE
    `table`.`field` IN (',`array`,')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass array to use in mysql, do something like

```html
$array  = implode(',',$array);

$query  = "CALL myStoredProcedure($array)";
```

And from my experience queries like `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column IN(?)` don't work you have  to put the `IN` values directly in the query