# Ajax post method, PHP limited insert query

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I add the data from open dialog to the table as `tdname[rowid]`. I am getting result as below.

```
        <form method="post" id="user_form">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="user_data">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="row_1">
                            <td>1 <input type="hidden" name="hidden_pid[]" id="pid1" class="pid" value="1"></td>
                            <td>K-60 <input type="hidden" name="hidden_p_code[]" id="p_code1" class="p_code" value="K-60"></td>
                            <td>Product 1<input type="hidden" name="hidden_p_name[]" id="p_name1" value="Product 1"></td>
                            <td> <input type="hidden" name="hidden_dekorA[]" id="dekorA1" value=""></td>
                            <td class="p_quantity">1 <input type="hidden" name="hidden_p_quantity[]" class="p_quantity1" id="p_quantity1" min="0" max="2500" step="1" value="1" data-type="1"></td>
                            <td>23.40 <input type="hidden" name="hidden_p_listprice[]" class="p_listprice1" id="p_listprice1" value="23.40" data-type="23.40"></td>
                            <td>23.40 <input type="hidden" name="hidden_p_netprice[]" id="p_netprice1" value="23.40"></td>
                            <td class="p_total">23.40 <input type="hidden" name="hidden_p_total[]" class="p_total" id="p_total1" value="23.40" for="1"></td>
                            <td>122 <input type="hidden" name="hidden_preorderno[]" id="preorderno1" class="preorderno" value="122"></td>
                        </tr>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    </tbody></table>
            </div>
            <div align="center">
                <button type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm Order</button>
            </div>
    </form>
```

Then I send the data to the `insert.php` file with the ajax post method.

```
     <script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#user_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
            var form_data = $("[name='hidden_pid[]'],[name='hidden_p_code[]'],[name='hidden_p_name[]'],[name='hidden_dekorA[]'],[name='hidden_p_quantity[]'],[name='hidden_p_listprice[]'],[name='hidden_p_netprice[]'],[name='hidden_p_total[]'],[name='hidden_preorderno[]']").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"insert.php",
                data : (form_data),
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert('OK');
                    
                },
                error:function(data){
                    alert('hata');
                }
            });
        
    }); 
});
</script>
```

I don't want to serialize all of items, so thats why im using like this serialize => `[name='hidden_pid[]']`
Im using stored procedure for insert. NEWLIST is my insert procedure.

`Insert.php` file:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=;charset=utf8;","username","pass");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try{
       
    $sp='NEWLIST';  
    $sql=sprintf('SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT ":",`parameter_name`) as `placeholders` FROM `information_schema`.`parameters` WHERE `SPECIFIC_NAME`="%s" and `specific_schema`="databasename"', $sp);
        
    $res=$db->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $placeholders=$res->placeholders;
    
    $sql=sprintf('call `%s`( %s );', $sp, $placeholders);     
    $keys=explode( ',', $placeholders );
    $size = count($_REQUEST['hidden_pid']);
    $count = 0;    
    $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
        
    while($count < $size){
        $main_arr = array(
            ':pid'          =>  $_REQUEST['hidden_pid'][$count],       
            ':p_code'       =>  $_REQUEST['hidden_p_code'][$count],
            ':p_name'       =>  $_REQUEST['hidden_p_name'][$count],
            ':dekorA'       =>  $_REQUEST['hidden_dekorA'][$count],
            ':p_quantity'   =>  $_REQUEST['hidden_p_quantity'][$count],
            ':p_listprice'  =>  $_REQUEST['hidden_p_listprice'][$count],
            ':p_netprice'   =>  $_REQUEST['hidden_p_netprice'][$count],
            ':p_total'      =>  $_REQUEST['hidden_p_total'][$count],
            ':preorderno'   =>  $_REQUEST['hidden_preorderno'][$count],
            ':yetkili'      =>  $_SESSION['id']
        );
        $count++;
        $data=array_combine($keys, array_values($main_arr));
        $stmt->execute($data);
    }
    
    $db->commit();

} catch( PDOException $e ){
    
    return "Insert failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$db = null;
```

This is working. But the problem is i can insert to mysql maximum 111 rows like this way. Im adding several hundred rows on form and ajax post sending value to insert.php but insert.php insert maximum 111 rows to mysql.
I also research on stackoverflow, people says `max_allowed_packet` value should 500MB. And i already do that. But still going on that issue.
The problem is on `insert.php`, i think. But how can i fix that issue i don't know. I would like to see your helps..

Its not working on my both servers:

1.Test server informations

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700, 3.2 GHz

RAM: 16 GB RAM

2.Raspberry pi 4 server informations

CPU: BCM2711, 1.5 GHz

RAM: 4 GB RAM

Comment: `max_allowed_packet` only limits the size of a single query. It shouldn't be a problem if you're making separate queries in a loop like this.

Comment: But what I don't understand about this code is that you're getting the stored procedure parameters dynamically from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but the code that creates `$main_arr` has the parameter order hard-coded. You should at least use `GROUP_CONCAT(parameter_name ORDER BY ordinal_position)`

Comment: What error are you getting if you try to insert more than 111 rows?

Comment: How can i do to seperate queries in a loop ?

Comment: Im getting first 111 rows

Comment: You *are* doing separate queries in the loop. Each time you call `$stmt->execute()` you're doing another query.

Comment: What does `echo $size;` show?

Comment: if i do `(this).serialize()` im getting 83 rows on mysql, so i decided to dont take decrease some of parameters from index.php

Comment: It doesnt show me anything, i couldnt see that, but i tried with manually, like $size = 200, but problem is still going on

Comment: I suspect you're hitting the PHP [`max_input_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) limit. It defaults to 1000.

Comment: I have int and varchar values in my database. Do I need to define them as pdo? Could the problem be caused by this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase the PHP [`max_input_vars`] setting in `php.ini`. The default value is 1,000. With 9 parameters in each row, that allows for only 111 rows.

Multiply the maximum number of rows you need to support by 9 and set it to something higher than this.

Comment: The problem is still going on.
[php.ini file](https://prnt.sc/ScVqsdftQblF)

Comment: The `max_input_vars` line is commented out with `;` so it's not working.

Comment: There is no more untagged max_input_vars with `;`. So should i clear to `;` ?

Comment: yes, of course. That's how you set a value other than the default.

Comment: I changed like your suggestion and restart to my server and it works ! Im trying to solve that issue like 1 week. I thought it was from my query or something like that. Thanks a lot anyway @Barmar. I would like to ask you 1 more simple question, sir. Whats the limitation of server about parameter inputs, is there any way to calculate that ?

Comment: There's no practical limit other than the amount of memory in your PHP process.